# How to declare a variable of type Html.ActionLink in Razor View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

What type can I declare a variable of type Html.ActionLink such that when I render this variable it renders normally. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
@{
    var action = @Html.DisplayFor(m => invoice.TransactionAction.Action);
    var link = "";
    var actionLink = "";
}
@{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(action.ToString()))
    {
        switch (action.ToString())
        {
            case "Receive Payment":
                link = "Receive Payment";
                actionLink = Html.ActionLink(@action.ToString(), @link, "Sales", new { id = invoice.Id }, null).ToString();
                break;
            case "Print":
                link = "Print";
                actionLink = Html.ActionLink(@action.ToString(), @link, "Sales", new { id = invoice.Id }, null).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I render `@actionLink`, it displays something like `<a href="/Sales/Receive%20Payment/7">Receive Payment</a>` which I understand to be  the ToString() equivalent of the Helper Method `ActionLink`.

Because I need to either display the link or null, I will like to know what type to declare actionLink.

**P.S: I have tried `var actionLink = Html.ActionLink("Sample", "Sample", "Sales");` but of course the null rendered Sample instead of not printing anything.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) actually returns [`MvcHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) and razor engines understands that it needs to render it as html.

You should store the result in variable of that type and then you can just render it normally without converting it to `String` like:

```
MvcHtmlString actionLink = Html.ActionLink(@action.ToString(), 
                                           @link, 
                                           "Sales", 
                                           new { id = invoice.Id }, 
                                           null);
```

and then you can use it anywhere on the view like:

```
<div>
@actionLink
</div>
```

and this would get rendered as html hyperlink.

Alternatively if we stick with the approach you are using using `String` then you can [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to render the string as html:

```
@Html.Raw(actionLink)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: With your help, I just had to assign actionLink to null. That is `MvcHtmlString actionLink = null;`. @action.ToString() can be null so calling ToString() on action can cause errors.